# Keyboard shortcuts (Autocomplete) for Squirrel SQL

Tags: squirrel-sql

I searched but could not quite find this information anywhere else. Could you list the best shortcut keys Squirrel?

I know it is possible to avoid a lot of typing with this feature of the tool.

The only one I know is to type `SF` and then press the spacebar. The result is `SELECT * FROM`.

Comment: @OP Please change the accepted answer to the top-voted one, as the currently accepted one does not answer your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to the Menu bar:
**Session** -> **Syntax** -> **Configure auto correct / abreviations**

Make sure that *Enable auto correct / abreviation* checkbox is selected. Here you can see the existing list and also add abreviations of your own ;)

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Using the menu option "Session-Syntax-Configure auto correct/abreviations" you can specify your own abreviations. I like to add `SCF` as an abreviation of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`.

Answer (score 9):

Following link lists a few keyboard shortcuts that might help
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/squirrel-sql/info

Comment: Not sure why this is an accepted answer.  The link in the answer doesn't answer what OP was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

In SQuirrel, to find keyboard shortcuts, press `ctrl + t` and you will see the list.